Full height of table in a page using mpdf (laravel-mpdf)
I'm trying to have a table with full height inside a page using the laravel-mpdf package.
This is what I've tried:
// The height of the table in a 100%
<table style="width=100%; height=100%">
  <tr> <td>Row 1</td> </tr>
  <tr> <td>Row 2</td> </tr>
</table>

// The height in each row
<table>
  <tr style="height="13px;">Row 1</tr>
  <tr style="height="13px;">Row 2</tr>
</table>

This is what I've get with both tests:

This is a layout of what I would to generate:


Can you elaborate on what you want. In the: "what i want" image, the table is to the left of the rows, aka the rows are not in the table. Is that correct?
